# Search specific annotations in mapView

Tags: swift, xcode, search, view, mkmapview

In my project i have a mapView with a lot of annotations & i would like to add a search functionality to the map so i can search those annotations and quickly find the annotation i want.

I followed a tutorial i found on the web but it searches globally (MKLocalSearch) and not the annotations.

I tried looking for a tutorial \ Help for my problem but i couldn't get any help for a long time now.
Here is my search code :

**I've made these annotations :**

```
let LitzmanLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32.100668,34.775192)
        // Drop a pin
        let Litzman = MKPointAnnotation()
        Litzman.coordinate = LitzmanLocation
        Litzman.title = "Litzman Bar"
        Litzman.subtitle = "נמל תל אביב 18,תל אביב"
        mapView.addAnnotation(Litzman)

        let ShalvataLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32.101145,34.775163)
        // Drop a pin
        let Shalvata = MKPointAnnotation()
        Shalvata.coordinate = ShalvataLocation
        Shalvata.title = "Shalvata"
        Shalvata.subtitle = "האנגר 28,נמל תל אביב"
        mapView.addAnnotation(Shalvata)


        let MarkidLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32.074961,34.781679)
        // Drop a pin
        let Markid = MKPointAnnotation()
        Markid.coordinate = MarkidLocation
        Markid.title = "Markid"
        Markid.subtitle = "אבן גבירול 30,תל אביב"
        mapView.addAnnotation(Markid)
```

## Currently the search i have:

**MapViewController:**

```
    //All my Map code is here
    }
    }
    }
    extension MapViewController: HandleMapSearch {
    func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark){
        // cache the pin
        selectedPin = placemark
        // clear existing pins
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = placemark.coordinate
        annotation.title = placemark.name
        if let _ = placemark.locality,
            let _ = placemark.administrativeArea {
            annotation.subtitle = ""
        }
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(placemark.coordinate, span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }  
}
```

**SearchTable:**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class LocationSearchTable : UITableViewController {

    var matchingItems = [CustomAnnotations]()
    var mapView: MKMapView? = nil

    var handleMapSearchDelegate:HandleMapSearch? = nil

    func parseAddress(selectedItem:MKPlacemark) -> String {
        // put a space between "4" and "Melrose Place"
        let firstSpace = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil && selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) ? " " : ""
        // put a comma between street and city/state
        let comma = (selectedItem.subThoroughfare != nil || selectedItem.thoroughfare != nil) && (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil || selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? ", " : ""
        // put a space between "Washington" and "DC"
        let secondSpace = (selectedItem.subAdministrativeArea != nil && selectedItem.administrativeArea != nil) ? " " : ""
        let addressLine = String(
            format:"%@%@%@%@%@%@%@",
            // street number
            selectedItem.subThoroughfare ?? "",
            firstSpace,
            // street name
            selectedItem.thoroughfare ?? "",
            comma,
            // city
            selectedItem.locality ?? "",
            secondSpace,
            // state
            selectedItem.administrativeArea ?? ""
        )
        return addressLine
    }

    func search(keywords:String) {
        self.matchingItems.removeAll()
        for annotation in self.mapView!.annotations {
            if annotation.isKindOfClass(CustomAnnotations) {
                //Just an example here for searching annotation by title, you could add other filtering actions else.
                if (annotation.title??.rangeOfString(keywords) != nil) {
                    self.matchingItems.append(annotation as! CustomAnnotations)
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}

extension LocationSearchTable : UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        guard let mapView = mapView,
            let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
        let request = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchBarText
        request.region = mapView.region
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.startWithCompletionHandler { response, _ in
            guard let response = response else {
                return
            }
            self.matchingItems = response.mapItems
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

}

extension LocationSearchTable {
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return matchingItems.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MapSearchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = selectedItem.title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = selectedItem.subtitle
        return cell
    }

}


extension LocationSearchTable {
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedItem = matchingItems[indexPath.row]//.placemark
        handleMapSearchDelegate?.dropPinZoomIn(selectedItem)
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

My question is how i can turn this to only search my annotations and not search all over the world with MKLocalSearch.

I'm a beginner coder using swift 3 and Xcode 8

Thanks you for helping.

Comment: What do you want to search annotations by? Name? Location? `MKLocalSearchRequest.region` does not constrain the search space, only prioritizes the selected `region`, so you can't do this with a `MKLocalSearchRequest`.

Comment: I would like to search by name to my specific annotations @PedroCastilho

Comment: @PedroCastilho how can i do that?

Comment: @PedroCastilho look ion chat please .. i have 1 last error.

Comment: @PedroCastilho i have 1 error only saying :  `Type 'LocationSearchTable' does not conform to protocol 'UISearchResultsUpdating'` I'm more specific in chat..

Answer (score 0):

You should just leave the `MKLocalSearch` out altogether if you really don't want to search the entire map. You can choose to prioritize a given region with `MKLocalSearchRequest.region`, but you can't actually constrain the search. Instead of that, you should loop over the `annotations` variable of your `MKMapView`.

```
extension String {
  func caseInsensitiveSearch(_ string: String) -> Bool {
    if self.lowercased().range(of: string.lowercased()) != nil {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }    
}

extension MKMapView {
    func searchForCustomAnnotation(like query: String) -> [MyCustomAnnotationClass] {
      let allAnnotations = self.annotations;
      return allAnotations.filter { annotation in
        if let customAnnotation = annotation as? MyCustomAnnotationClass {
          return customAnnotation.title.caseInsensitiveSearch(query);
        }
      }
   }
}
```

EDIT: I just noticed you said you were using Swift 2.3, my code is Swift 3. If you're using Swift 2.3, you should change the `String.caseInsensitiveSearch` method to:

```
extension String {
  func caseInsensitiveSearch(_ string: String) -> Bool {
    if self.lowercaseString.rangeOfString(string.lowercaseString) != nil {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }    
}
```

You can then use `searchForCustomAnnotation` on your `MKMapView` to get a list of all annotations with a title containing your search query.

Your code would look like this:

```
extension LocationSearchTable: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        guard let mapView = mapView, 
              let searchBarText = searchController.searchBar.text else { return }
            self.matchingItems = mapView.searchForCustomAnnotation(like: searchBarText);
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what i need to put instead of the MKLocalSearch?

Comment: You don't need to use the MKLocalSearch if you use this method.

Comment: yes I'm using that but i don't know what to put instead of that on my code

Comment: You can add my code to your app anywhere, then in your extension which implements `UISearchResultsUpdating` you can call `searchForCustomAnnotation` on your `MKMapView` and then set the resulting array as your table's data. This also has the benefit of not being asynchronous.

Comment: I added a part of what your code would look like. This would also enable you to remove all the code related to your `MKLocalSearch`.

Comment: You should replace `MyCustomAnnotationClass` by the actual annotation class you're using. Based on your code, that seems to be `CustomAnnotations`. `MyCustomAnnotationClass` is just a placeholder I used because I don't know what is your actual annotation class. Re: your other issue, I'll edit my answer. Essentially, just remove the parens from `lowercaseString()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139521/discussion-between-pedro-castilho-and-newbie-questions).